# Discrepancies between debug/release profiles when counting items from a plist for numberOfItemsInSection for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, build, plist, uicollectionview, initwithcontentsoffile

I have a UICollectionView whose collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection: is defined as follows:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.contents.count;
}
```

self.contents is lazily allocated as follows:

```
- (NSArray *)contents
{
    if (!_contents) {
        _contents = [[XYZSharedMemoryStore sharedStore] clContents];
    }
    return _contents;
}
```

clContents returns an NSArray, as follows:

```
- (NSArray *)clContents
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cl_contents" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *products = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    return products;
}
```

XYZSharedMemoryStore is a singleton defined as follows:

```
+ (id)sharedStore
{
    static XYZSharedMemoryStore *sharedStore = nil;
    if (!sharedStore) {
        sharedStore = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }
    return sharedStore;
}


+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    return [self sharedStore];
}


- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // STUFF
    }
    return self;
}
```

Going full circle, the problem I'm having is that self.contents.count in collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection: returns 0 when I'm in a release profile and the correct number (10) in debug mode, so in the release profile, my UICollectionView doesn't display any cells.  The profiles are in the default state that Xcode creates them in.

Any ideas what might be going on here?

Comment: Try to find Optimization Level property in Build Settings for your target and switch it for debug profile to "-Os" (the same as for Release). If the problem will appear in debug mode I guess this is memory related problem.

Comment: Ok, that definitely causes the debug profile to behave the same.  Memory related, you say?

Comment: Yes, ARC behaviour could be little bit different for lower optimization level and may not release things properly (in a proper time). Propably count is 0 because self.contents is nil. Please check that with opt level set to -Os in debug and this will give us another clue :)

Comment: Yeah, I set it to -Os in debug, from -O0 originally, and the problem happened.  Would it be ill-advised to lower the optimization level for the release profile?

Comment: Still seems a little strange.  self.contents, as a getter, should be a blocking call that ends by assigning a value to the _contents ivar ...

Comment: You were right.  I set self.contents as a weak reference, so I guess I made a mistake all along, and the lack of optimization in debug was letting it slip through the cracks.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this was a case of programmer error ...

I was setting my **self.contents** as a weak reference, so by all rights it should have been deallocated immediately and always returning a count of 0.  Since the **debug** configuration has an optimization level of **None [-O0]**, it wasn't deallocating immediately, allowing me to use it.

The **release** configuration is set to **Fastest, Smallest [-Os]**, causing the weakly-referenced array to deallocate immediately, not allowing my UICollectionView to pick up its values.

Thanks to Artur Ozierański for his help.